# Image change the shape when displaying

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to display this image as i have this image in my directory

[image]

but i displaying it with this code

```
Mat img=imread("D:\\vig.png");
imshow("image",img);
waitKey();
imwrite("D:\\img.jpg",img);
```

The same image displayed as follows

[image]

Whats wrong with it

Comment: If the image has an alpha channel, you might want to try `Mat img=imread("D:\\vig.png", -1)`

Comment: tried , didnt work , image is actually looks hollow from inside

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your vignette is only in the alpha [4th] channel, and also it looks inverted (opacity values here).

(your 1st picture seems to show a proper alpha composite with a white image(or background), that's probably from photoshop or the like. )

```
Mat img=imread("vig.png",-1); // load 'as is', don't convert to bgr !!
Mat ch[4]; 
split(img,ch);

Mat im2 = ch[3];              // here's the vignette

// im2 = 255 - im2;           // eventually cure the inversion

imshow("image",im2);
waitKey();
imwrite("img.jpg",im2);
```

[image]

again, note, that opencv won't do any alpha-compositing, you'll have to roll your own formulas for that.

Comment: yes berak my image is from photoshop but opencv didn't make something like as my image above as far i tried , because above is just like hollow from the center

Comment: another fly's life, btw ? ;)

Comment: aahh i just change the name here BERAK