# Why image is not merging

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to blend 2 image in my code below

```
Mat input = imread ("E:\\img1.jpg");
Mat image;
Mat img12=imread("D:\\vig.png",-1);  // load 'as is', don't convert to bgr !!
Mat ch[4]; 
split(img12,ch);
Mat im2 = ch[3];              // here's the vignette
im2 = 255 - im2; 
im2.convertTo(im2 , input.type());
resize(im2,image,Size(input.rows,input.cols));
blending_overlay(image , input , image);
imshow ("image",image);
waitKey();
```

different operation on [img12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562207/image-change-the-shape-when-displaying) is because of it shape , code giving me the runtime error of

[image]

Comment: resize(im2,image,Size(input.rows,input.cols)); // Size is w,h, Mat is rows,cols

Comment: after changing the values still getting the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @berak commented, you are not using [`cv::Size`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#size) correctly, whose first parameter is `width`, and second `height` (not the other way around).

Change

```
resize(im2, image, Size(input.rows, input.cols));
```

to

```
resize(im2, image, Size(input.cols, input.rows));
```

---

**Update:** You further need to address `image` that is passed in to function `blending_overlay`. It has only one channel, but you're trying to access other channels from it:

```
float target = (float)img1.at<uchar>(i, 3*j+c)/255.0 ; // img1 = image here
```

Comment: @AHF Show the definition of `blending_overlay()`.

Comment: i change `Mat image2 = Mat(input.size(),input.type());` and `blending_overlay(image , input , image2);` but still the same error

Comment: @AHF The error is on the first parameter that you passed in, which is still `image`.

Comment: @AHF Like I said, that's because, `im2` has only one channel while you're trying to access other channels of it in the function.

Comment: it solves , but It effect the result because of channels , is there any way to solve it in a better way

Comment: @AHF You probably need to handle different for images with different channels, just like treating it as a special case.

Comment: +1 , when i draw the same image in photoshop it didnt show any brightness in center but when i use it here it shows brightness , am asking about img12