# Merging two images showing brightness

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to blend two image or you can say put one image on other image , when i apply blending overlay on the image or simple merge two image it show me brightness in it.

here are my two images (first vignette is empty from inside , its not containing brightness in the centre )

[image]

and the other is

[image]

The code which i did is

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat img=imread("E:\\vig.png",-1); 
    Mat ch[4]; 
    split(img,ch);
    Mat im2 = ch[3];              // here's the vignette
    im2 = 255 - im2; // eventually cure the inversion
    Mat img2 = imread("E:\\ew.jpg");
    Mat out2;
    blending_overlay3(img2 , im2 , out2);
    imshow("image",out2);
    imwrite("E:\\image.jpg",out2);
    waitKey();}
```

It show me the result like

[image]

but i require result like

[image]

**EDIT**

The first image is hollow/empty from center (the vignette one) , but when i read the image (vignette one) with my program then it become solid(bright) from the center , the history behind its implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562207/image-change-the-shape-when-display%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bing)

There is the only problem and its with first (vignette) image reading , if it read as it is , like hollow/empty from the center , so that the other image with which we merge/blend/weight whatever apply it didn't effect the center part of the image , not even show brightness etc , that's what i want to do

Comment: -1. There are too many possible answers to this question with the information given. It is not a problem with the code but the approach. A few sample questions to try and answer are below
 
When you change the weighting is that result different to the one you show in your question? How does it vary for the different weightings? Have you tried changing your background image to make it the process different?

Comment: any possible working answer will be accepted , the image was first hollow/empty from center (the vignette one) , but when i read the image (vignette one) with my program then it become solid from the center , the history behind this is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562207/image-change-the-shape-when-displaying`

Comment: there is the only problem with that first (vignette) image reading , if it read as it is , like hollow/empty from the center , so that the other image with which we merge/blend/weight whateva apply it didn't effect the center part of the image , not even show brightness etc

Comment: possible duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/22654770/creating-vignette-filter-in-opencv

Comment: @AbidRahmanK No there is a difference , that vignette is radial gradient in which the white portion contain alpha/brightness , but the question here is that i am merging this vignette (which is hollow/empty from center like the frame , like effect are on the sides and no effect on the center of the image) with the image

Comment: i tried that way , it give me the image , which i load in my question as "result image" , but its not giving me the required image , in which vignette is applied but no effect on the center of the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's me again :) It seems you are writing new photoshop.

The result I've got:
[image]

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
 int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    namedWindow("Image");

    Mat Img1=imread("Img1.png",-1);
    Mat Img2=imread("Img2.png");
    cv::resize(Img1,Img1,Img2.size());
    Img1.convertTo(Img1,CV_32FC4,1.0/255.0);
    Img2.convertTo(Img2,CV_32FC3,1.0/255.0);

    vector<Mat> ch; 
    split(Img1,ch);

    Mat mask = ch[3].clone();              // here's the vignette

    ch.resize(3);

    Mat I1,I2,result;

    cv::multiply(mask,ch[0],ch[0]);
    cv::multiply(mask,ch[1],ch[1]);
    cv::multiply(mask,ch[2],ch[2]);
    merge(ch,I1);

    vector<Mat> ch2(3);
    split(Img2,ch2);
    cv::multiply(1.0-mask,ch2[0],ch2[0]);
    cv::multiply(1.0-mask,ch2[1],ch2[1]);
    cv::multiply(1.0-mask,ch2[2],ch2[2]);
    merge(ch2,I2);

    result=I1+I2;

    imshow("Image",result);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: if will not gonna get the answer in a day or two , i surely msg you :) btw thank you @Andrey , if i gonna make new PS , surely mention your credit there too :)

Comment: What if i did the same with the image which has red sides , like vignette is red

Comment: Then you need mix them pixel by pixel using tranparensy layer as mix coeffs (m - in formula). The formula for red layer (apply it for each pair of images layers) is: Iresult_Red=I1_Red(x,y)*m(x,y)+I2_Red(x,y)*(1.0-m(x,y)); Then you'll be able to use any image with transparency layer as vignette. Didn't  test it but seems it should work.

Comment: Found my mistake (but it works with it :) ). Change Img1.convertTo(Img1,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0); to Img1.convertTo(Img1,CV_32FC4,1.0/255.0); (I've corrected in answer.)

Comment: I change it , but i am afraid how much it take my time to become a good problem solver like this !! so that i can deal with every situation

Comment: why you did this `1.0/255.0` in `covertTo` function and what effect this `multiply(1.0-mask,ch2[0],ch2[0]);`

Comment: I've mentioned that I like [0;1] interval it is very convenient in many cases. But for mask it mandatory because mask defines amount of each part in result. And sum of the coefficients must be equal to 1.0 (100%). Suppose the whole result is 100% (1.0) then mix 30% (0.3) of first image 70% (0.7) of second image.

Comment: When mask=1.0 then result is first image, but when mask=0.0 result image is the second image. All between gives us mix.

Line multiply(1.0-mask,ch2[0],ch2[0]); is just a per element multiplication ch[2] with 1.0-mask see formula above.

Comment: when i write this image `imwrite("D:\\redvig.png" , result);` why its write it as whole black

Comment: I guess because before saving you didn't convert it (after scaling by factor 255) to CV_8UC3 data type.