# Calling image in imageView distory the resultant image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, image-processing

I am using Android NDKwith OpenCV.
I have two input images as input and one output image.
The first input image is just a normal image and the second is a vignette.

**I am getting some kind of logical error from java side.**

Below is my code of java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         imageview_1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         imageview_2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        InputStream is , Vign;
        is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.me);
        final Bitmap bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        Vign = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.p);
        final Bitmap bmInImg2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Vign);

        mPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
        nPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
        vPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg2.getWidth() * bmInImg2.getHeight()];
        imageview_1.setImageBitmap(bmInImg);
        // Copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
        bmInImg.getPixels(mPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());
        bmInImg2.getPixels(vPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), bmInImg2.getHeight());

        mCannyOutArray = new int[bmInImg2.getWidth() * bmInImg2.getHeight()];
        final Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg2.getWidth(), bmInImg2.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
        bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), bmInImg2.getHeight());

        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View v)  {  

                if (count ==0)
                {
                    Vig(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(),bmInImg2.getHeight(),bmInImg2.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray,vPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray); 

                    bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), bmInImg2.getHeight());    
                    imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);        
                }

                count++;        
            }
            }); 

        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        String outFileName = extStorageDirectory + "/me.png";
        OutputBitmapToFile(bmOutImg, outFileName);      
    }
```

The above code gives me the vignette fine as output but first image is showing lining on all image and when I add both images the vignette looks fine but image (image1) inside vignette is full of lines, if I change the code of `bmOutImg.setPixels` from outside and inside condition `if` to

```
Vig(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(),bmInImg2.getHeight(),bmInImg2.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray,vPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray); 

bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());   
                        imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
```

Then it shows lining on vignette image. What should be my `mCannyOutArray` should be so that both my images give a satisfactory result for my output when I add vig+image1

Vig is :

[image]

and img1 is :

[image]

output:

[image]

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="208dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: I update with Pictures

Comment: what about the output images with "lining"?

Comment: Does the problem still occur when `vig` and `img1` have the same dimensions?

Comment: hey @karlphillip nice to see you on my question , i am just reading your answer , yes output will not show `vig` if we use `img1` dimensions for output

Comment: @AHF Unfortunately I don't have my system setup properly to run your code, so I'm just guessing what could be wrong. It's very important that `vig` and `img1` be created (or be scaled) to have the **exact same dimensions** before any operation takes place. Of course, `output` should have the same dimension of the input images.

Comment: @karlphillip Thanks, I am resizing both images on `jni` c++ end , do I need to resize them on java end too ?

Comment: @AHF Print their sizes to the console and you will know.

Comment: having different dimensions seems to be the source of your problem, i do think the same as @karlphillip... try using images of the same dimension and if that works, scale your blender image to the size of your picture and add them after that together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to identify **where is the problem**:

- Is it on your implementation of the vignette filter?
- Or is it in the way the images are being displayed on the screen?

To assist you on that, be sure `vig` and `img1` have the same dimensions before they undergo any processing. Save those images to the disk and inspect their width/height values.

Then execute your filter, and save the output image to the hard disk before it's displayed on the screen. If the saved image looks OK, then you know for sure the problem is the way that the images are being displayed.

A while back I implemented a [vignette filter using C++ and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22876759/176769), you can take a look at the source code and compare it to what you are doing. Here's an example:

**Input:**

[image]
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: yes that answer was on my question too , but here the scenario is different , the vignette image is a separate 4 channel image of photoshop and i am trying to implement it using the logic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801988/merging-two-images-showing-brightness , I identify the problem on my java end which I mention above , because my `jni code of c++` is working fine but how to resize two bitmaps ? first convert them to Mat ? in java , these filters work for me on windows , i am facing problem in androoid

Comment: Sorry, can't help you any further because of my lack of experience in JNI. If I were you, I would go to the **documentation of the data type** that is being used to store the image, and see if it provides a method to resize the image.

Comment: that logic of both images should be of same size work for me , I just did it manually by using both image of same size , now I check it further that how I can resize two images in java , Thanks